# Does Swift have access modifiers?

Tags: access-modifiers, swift

In Objective-C instance data can be `public`, `protected` or `private`. For example:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
{
  @public
    int x;
  @protected:
    int y;
  @private:
    int z;
  }
-(int) apple;
-(int) pear;
-(int) banana;
@end
```

I haven't found any mention of access modifiers in the Swift reference. Is it possible to limit the visibility of data in Swift?

Comment: Added an answer updated for [final version of Xcode 6.1.1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28932875/1548472)

Comment: *Swift 4* [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-has-access-modifiers/39697920#39697920).

Answer (score 453, accepted):

[As of **Swift 3.0.1**, there are **4 levels of access**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html), described below from the highest (least restrictive) to the lowest (most restrictive).

---

#### 1. `open` and `public`

Enable an entity to be used outside the defining module (target). You typically use `open` or `public` access when specifying the public interface to a framework.

However, **`open` access applies only to classes and class members**, and it differs from `public` access as follows:

- `public` classes and class members can only be subclassed and overridden within the defining module (target).
- `open` classes and class members can be subclassed and overridden both within and outside the defining module (target).

```
// First.framework – A.swift

open class A {}
```

```
// First.framework – B.swift

public class B: A {} // ok
```

```
// Second.framework – C.swift

import First

internal class C: A {} // ok
```

```
// Second.framework – D.swift

import First

internal class D: B {} // error: B cannot be subclassed
```

#### 2. `internal`

Enables an entity to be used within the defining module (target). You typically use `internal` access when defining an app’s or a framework’s internal structure.

```
// First.framework – A.swift

internal struct A {}
```

```
// First.framework – B.swift

A() // ok
```

```
// Second.framework – C.swift

import First

A() // error: A is unavailable
```

#### 3. `fileprivate`

Restricts the use of an entity to its defining source file. You typically use `fileprivate` access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality when those details are used within an entire file.

```
// First.framework – A.swift

internal struct A {

    fileprivate static let x: Int

}

A.x // ok
```

```
// First.framework – B.swift

A.x // error: x is not available
```

#### 4. `private`

Restricts the use of an entity to its enclosing declaration. You typically use `private` access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality when those details are used only within a single declaration.

```
// First.framework – A.swift

internal struct A {

    private static let x: Int

    internal static func doSomethingWithX() {
        x // ok
    }

}

A.x // error: x is unavailable
```

Comment: Could someone explain to me why isn't this a big deal?

Comment: I don't know if it is good news, as  “protocols” with factories lead to a cleaner design.

Comment: There _always_ are some methods or variables in OOP that should be private or protected. This allows for implementing [SOLID design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), as big methods are divided to a number of smaller ones, each with its own responsibility, that can be overriden, but only the "main" method should be available for public usage.

Comment: I asked a swift engineer this question and raised the concerns about safety and how it goes against the philosophy of swift. He said it was a popular request and we should file a report for it. I'm really glad that they confirmed it already!

Comment: Well, with a protocol and a factory you'll have at least 3 types when you need only one. Sometimes it's good, but not always. I don't think that having at least twice the amount of types (a protocol for each class) is alwa6s cleaner. Keep It Stupid Simple.

Comment: For apps, this shouldn't be a big deal because your code will be consumed by no one else but you and your dev team. In that case just prepend "private" members with an underscore(or for hilarity, a really obscure unicode character/emoji) and call it your team's "Best practice". I can see the problem for library and open-source developers though. The good thing is that the only IDE that can compile Swift so far is still in BETA, which means we can hope that we'll get this before the public release.

Comment: I indeed had third-party libraries in mind (both open- and closed-source, because now we can create true frameworks for iOS).

Comment: I, personally don't like solutions like the one with the underscore/special-char leading "private" methods. Even if it is guaranteed that i for myself will be the only person ever having a look at this code, it makes the code more save / less prone to errors cause the compiler will simply prevent you from doing things you should not do. So I think they should get out the "access control mechanisms" as fast as possible, so people wont get used to bad habits.

Comment: @sh4kesbeer: In very few languages are access modifiers a security measure. In dynamic languages like C# or Java you can reflect private members out, and languages like c++ offer zero safety as a rule. Access modifiers are a codified convention with no more real world "prevention" than _method conventions. Access modifiers look cleaner and have various nicer semantics, but either can be called or not from outside code.

Comment: @Phoshi If a language has access modifiers, developers (i.e. framework developers) may use them or decide not to do so. In everything-is-public languages, those who want to prevent "unauthorized access", have no other choice than having to implement some twisted security checks to do so. Having those modifiers does no harm, only eases developers' lifes. By the way, it's been **31 years** since the introduction of C++, why not move forward?

Comment: The Xcode 6 beta release notes say: "Access control (public/private members) is not enabled in this seed. (15747445)"

Comment: I was really surprised that this didn't work out of the box, but good to hear that it's on the way. I will mark stuff that should be set private with comments for the time being, to be able to easily implement it later.

Comment: @akashivskyy There's no such thing as "unauthorized access". No human can predict for all time that no one else will ever need to access an internal method of a class. It's the consumer who's in charge of how they want to use code, not the creator. As has been noted, you can always get around it anyway, so just like copy protection it only inconveniences good people.

Comment: @FlorianRachor But if the world doesn't explode in the meantime, maybe that's a sign that you never really needed it in the first place?

Comment: @alcalde Yeou're right, we cannot predict that. Users may even alter the source files, changing `protected` to `public`. But it doesn't mean that access modifiers are useless. It's like saying that annotating the return type of a method is useless *(if it wasn't for the compiler)*, because a method can return whatever it wants. Access modifiers are an important part of clean and readable API, just like type annotations.

Comment: @alcalde Depends on how large your team is. If more then two persons or even two teams are working on the code you need this stuff. Sure you could try and communicate that certain functions are not meant to use public, but in my experience this never works. If it's coded in, I save myself a lot of time and annoying emails.

Comment: @alcalde The idea of a public interface is highly valuable.  If you intend that all code in a class must reside inside functions that are part of the public API, I think that's quite limiting.  On the other hand, having a specified public API allows the implementation to change (including use of private methods) without disrupting consumers.  If someone 'needs' to use an internal class method I feel they are misunderstanding the limits of the class' functionality (or are trying to use a buggy class).

Comment: It's nice that Apple developers still listen to the third-party ones. :)

Comment: However you can't add a target for a UIController inherited class to invoke a private method in the same class. Which is a big bummer.

Comment: Why? When you're giving away your selector it can't private antymore.

Comment: Is there a way to set a whole bunch of things private at once in Swift, or do you have to write private on every line?

Comment: You have to write it on every line, unfortunately.

Comment: No "protected" modifier? You've got to be kidding me.

Comment: @gangelo: No, this is not a joke. Swift Core Team explained the decision in a blog post: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=11 and there was an extensive mailing list discussion on swift-evolution: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160328/013665.html

Answer (score 39):

## Swift 4 / Swift 5

As per mentioned in the [Swift Documentation - Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html), Swift has *5 Access Controls*:

- ***open*** and ***public***: can be accessed from their module's entities and any module's entities that imports the defining module.
- ***internal***: can only be accessed from their module's entities. It is the default access level.
- ***fileprivate*** and ***private***: can only be accessed in limited within a limited scope where you define them.

---

## What is the difference between *open* and *public*?

**open** is the same as public in previous versions of Swift, they allow classes from other modules to use and inherit them, i.e: they can be subclassed from other modules. Also, they allow members from other modules to use and override them. The same logic goes for their modules.

**public** allow classes from other module to use them, but *not* to inherit them, i.e: they *cannot* be subclassed from other modules. Also, they allow members from other modules to use them, but NOT to override them. For their modules, they have the same open's logic (they allow classes to use and inherit them; They allow members to use and override them).

## What is the difference between *fileprivate* and *private*?

**fileprivate** can be accessed from the their entire files.

**private** can only be accessed from their single declaration and to *extensions* of that declaration that are in the same file; For instance:

```
// Declaring "A" class that has the two types of "private" and "fileprivate":
class A {
    private var aPrivate: String?
    fileprivate var aFileprivate: String?

    func accessMySelf() {
        // this works fine
        self.aPrivate = ""
        self.aFileprivate = ""
    }
}

// Declaring "B" for checking the abiltiy of accessing "A" class:
class B {
    func accessA() {
        // create an instance of "A" class
        let aObject = A()

        // Error! this is NOT accessable...
        aObject.aPrivate = "I CANNOT set a value for it!"

        // this works fine
        aObject.aFileprivate = "I CAN set a value for it!"
    }
}
```

---

## What are the differences between Swift 3 and Swift 4 Access Control?

As mentioned in the [SE-0169 proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0169-improve-interaction-between-private-declarations-and-extensions.md), the only refinement has been added to Swift 4 is that the *private* access control scope has been expanded to be accessible from *extensions* of that declaration in the same file; For instance:

```
struct MyStruct {
    private let myMessage = "Hello World"
}

extension MyStruct {
    func printMyMessage() {
        print(myMessage)
        // In Swift 3, you will get a compile time error:
        // error: 'myMessage' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level

        // In Swift 4 it should works fine!
    }
}
```

So, there is no need to declare `myMessage` as *fileprivate* to be accessible in the whole file.

Answer (score 17):

When one talks about making a "private method" in Swift or ObjC (or ruby or java or…) those methods aren't *really* private. There's no actual access control around them. Any language that offers even a little introspection lets developers get to those values from outside the class if they really want to.

So what we're really talking about here is a way to define a public-facing interface that merely *presents* the functionality we want it to, and "hides" the rest that we consider "private".

The Swift mechanism for declaring interfaces is the `protocol`, and it can be used for this purpose.

```
protocol MyClass {
  var publicProperty:Int {get set}
  func publicMethod(foo:String)->String
}

class MyClassImplementation : MyClass {
  var publicProperty:Int = 5
  var privateProperty:Int = 8

  func publicMethod(foo:String)->String{
    return privateMethod(foo)
  }

  func privateMethod(foo:String)->String{
    return "Hello \(foo)"
  }
}
```

Remember, protocols are first-class types and can be used anyplace a type can. *And*, when used this way, they only expose their own interfaces, not those of the implementing type.

Thus, as long as you use `MyClass` instead of `MyClassImplementation` in your parameter types, etc. it should all just work:

```
func breakingAndEntering(foo:MyClass)->String{
  return foo.privateMethod()
  //ERROR: 'MyClass' does not have a member named 'privateMethod'
}
```

There are some cases of direct assignment where you have to be explicit with type instead of relying on Swift to infer it, but that hardly seems a deal breaker:

```
var myClass:MyClass = MyClassImplementation()
```

Using protocols this way is semantic, reasonably concise, and to my eyes looks a lot like the Class Extentions we've been using for this purpose in ObjC.

Comment: If protocols don't allow us to have a default argument, how can I create a public method with optional parameters that still complies with the protocol?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The following creates a public method with an optional parameter. There doesn't seem to be a problem: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/17d8d2d25a78644046b6

Comment: For some reason the optional parameter is not working as it should on my project, had already tried something similar to your GitHub example. As we can't set a default parameter on a protocol, I got stuck and ended up asking a question. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: We all know that anything is hackable. We just need some order whats why we need access modifiers

Answer (score 14):

As far as I can tell, there are no keywords 'public', 'private' or 'protected'. This would suggest everything is public.

However Apple may be expecting people to use “[protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_345)” (called interfaces by the rest of the world) and the [factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29) to hide details of the implementation type.

This is often a good design pattern to use anyway; as it lets you change your **implementation** class hierarchy,  while keeping the **logical** type system the same.

Comment: This is nice as it also reduces coupling and can make testing easier.

Comment: That would work better if there was a way to hide the implementation class of the protocol, but there doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Can anyone provide an illustrative example of this pattern?

Comment: Well, this answer was valid in the previous Swift version(s), it seems that it is not valid anymore :) please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-has-access-modifiers/39697920#39697920).

Answer (score 12):

Using a combination of protocols, closures, and nested/inner classes, it's possible to use something along the lines of the module pattern to hide information in Swift right now. It's not super clean or nice to read but it does work.

Example:

```
protocol HuhThing {
  var huh: Int { get set }
}

func HuhMaker() -> HuhThing {
   class InnerHuh: HuhThing {
    var innerVal: Int = 0
    var huh: Int {
      get {
        return mysteriousMath(innerVal)
      }

      set {
       innerVal = newValue / 2
      }
    }

    func mysteriousMath(number: Int) -> Int {
      return number * 3 + 2
    }
  }

  return InnerHuh()
}

HuhMaker()
var h = HuhMaker()

h.huh      // 2
h.huh = 32 
h.huh      // 50
h.huh = 39
h.huh      // 59
```

innerVal and mysteriousMath are hidden here from outside use and attempting to dig your way into the object should result in an error.

I'm only part of the way through my reading of the Swift docs so if there's a flaw here please point it out, would love to know.

Comment: ok, i thought about this solution too, but explain me, why i cannot acces with h.huh.innerVal?

Comment: Swift is type-safe and the only thing the external world knows about h is that it complies to HuhThing. HuhThing does not include any information about a property called innerVal and so attempting to access it is an error.

Comment: Still accessible :P
`reflect(h)[0].1.value // 19`

Comment: Nice find there John - I wasn't aware of reflect. Seems to turn objects into Tuples - is there any official documentation on that function or other metaprogramming stuff in Swift? I took a look through the language guide on iBooks but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: I just found `reflect` in the headers when browsing for what `Mirror` was because they keep popping up in autocomplete.

Comment: @JohnEstropia I don't think reflection counts. In Java (a more mature language), there _are_ access modifiers, but they don't prevent reflection tricks either.

Comment: @11684: Note that I do think Dave's method is elegant enough, but he did ask to mention any flaws so I showed that there is still a way to extract hidden classes, methods, and properties.

Comment: It would probably be hard to get people to universally agree if this is a flaw or not, but it's definitely worth knowing, so I'm very glad it was pointed out. :)

Answer (score 10):

As of Xcode 6 beta 4, Swift has access modifiers. From the release notes:

> Swift access control has three access levels:
>
> - **private** entities can only be accessed from within the source file where they are defined.
> - **internal** entities can be accessed anywhere within the target where they are defined.
> - **public** entities can be accessed from anywhere within the target and from any other context that imports the current target’s module.

The implicit default is `internal`, so within an application target you can leave access modifiers off except where you want to be more restrictive. In a framework target (e.g. if you're embedding a framework to share code between an app and an sharing or Today view extension), use `public` to designate API you want to expose to clients of your framework.

Comment: Well, this answer was valid in the previous Swift version(s), it seems that it is not valid anymore :) please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-has-access-modifiers/39697920#39697920).

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3.0 provides five different access controls:**

1. open
2. public
3. internal
4. fileprivate
5. private

> **Open** access and **public** access enable entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, and also in a
>   source file from another module that imports the defining module. You
>   typically use open or public access when specifying the public
>   interface to a framework.
>
> **Internal** access enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, but not in any source file outside of that
>   module. You typically use internal access when defining an app’s or a
>   framework’s internal structure.
>
> **File-private** access restricts the use of an entity to its own defining source file. Use file-private access to hide the
>   implementation details of a specific piece of functionality when those
>   details are used within an entire file.
>
> **Private** access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration. Use private access to hide the implementation details of
>   a specific piece of functionality when those details are used only
>   within a single declaration.
>
> ***Open*** access is the highest (least restrictive) access level and **private** access is the lowest (most restrictive) access level.

**Default Access Levels**

All entities in your code (with a few specific exceptions) have a default access level of internal if you do not specify an explicit access level yourself. As a result, in many cases you do not need to specify an explicit access level in your code.

**The release note on the topic:**

> Classes declared as public can no longer be subclassed outside of
>   their defining module, and methods declared as public can no longer be
>   overridden outside of their defining module. To allow a class to be
>   externally subclassed or a method to be externally overridden, declare
>   them as open, which is a new access level beyond public. Imported
>   Objective-C classes and methods are now all imported as open rather
>   than public. Unit tests that import a module using an @testable import
>   will still be allowed to subclass public or internal classes as well
>   as override public or internal methods. (SE-0117)

More information & details :
[The Swift Programming Language (Access Control)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

Comment: Well, this answer was valid in the previous Swift version(s), it seems that it is not valid anymore :) please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-has-access-modifiers/39697920#39697920).

Answer (score 4):

In Beta 6, the documentation states that there are three different access modifiers:

- Public
- Internal
- Private

And these three apply to Classes, Protocols, functions and properties.

```
public var somePublicVariable = 0
internal let someInternalConstant = 0
private func somePrivateFunction() {}
```

For more, check *[Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)*.

Comment: There should've been a protected modifier which eases creating classes with greater security.

Comment: Well, this answer was valid in the previous Swift version(s), it seems that it is not valid anymore :) please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-has-access-modifiers/39697920#39697920).

Answer (score 2):

**For Swift 1-3:**

No, it's not possible. There aren't any private/protected methods and variables at all.

Everything is public.

**Update**
Since Swift 4, it's possible see other answers in this thread

Comment: This comment is accurate for the current seed.

Comment: For the current seed. [It will appear in the future](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24012515/573976).

Comment: "public" / "protected" / "private" do not currently exist, but you can hide things using closures, protocols, and inner classes - this makes it somewhat like the module pattern used in JavaScript commonly. Please see my sample code on my reply here for an example of how to do this. If I'm mistaken about how it works and my example is incorrect please point that out as I'm still learning too. :)

Comment: It seems that it is not valid anymore :) please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-has-access-modifiers/39697920#39697920).

Answer (score 2):

Now in beta 4, they've added access modifiers to Swift.

from [Xcode 6 beta 4 realese notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_4_o2p8fz/xcode_6_beta_4_release_notes.pdf):

> Swift access control has three access levels:
>
> - `private` entities can only be accessed from within the source ﬁle where they are deﬁned.
> - `internal` entities can be accessed anywhere within the target where they are deﬁned.
> - `public` entities can be accessed from anywhere within the target and from any other context
>   that imports the current target’s module.
>
> By default, most entities in a source ﬁle have internal access. This allows application developers
> to largely ignore access control while allowing framework developers full control over a
> framework's API.

Comment: Well, this answer was valid in the previous Swift version(s), it seems that it is not valid anymore :) please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-has-access-modifiers/39697920#39697920).

Answer (score 2):

## Access control mechanisms as [introduced in Xcode 6](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID5):

> Swift provides three different access levels for entities within your code. These access levels are relative to the source file in which an entity is defined, and also relative to the module that source file belongs to.
>
> - *Public access* enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, and also in a source file from another module that imports the defining module. You typically use public access when specifying the public interface to a framework.
> - *Internal access* enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, but not in any source file outside of that module. You typically use internal access when defining an app’s or a framework’s internal structure.
> - *Private access* restricts the use of an entity to its own defining source file. Use private access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality.
>
> Public access is the highest (least restrictive) access level and private access is the lowest (or most restrictive) access level.

Default accecss it *internal*, and does as such not need to be specified. Also note that the *private* specifier does **not** work on the class level, but on the source file level. This means that to get parts of a class really private you need to separate into a file of its own. This also introduces some interesting cases with regards to unit testing...

Another point to me made, which is commented upon in the link above, is that you can't 'upgrade' the access level. If you subclass something, you can restrict it more, but not the other way around.

This last bit also affects functions, tuples and surely other stuff in the way that if i.e. a function uses a *private* class, then it's not valid to have the function *internal* or *public*, as they might not have access to the *private* class. This results in a compiler warning, and you need to redeclare the function as a *private* function.

Comment: Well, this answer was valid in the previous Swift version(s), it seems that it is not valid anymore :) please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-has-access-modifiers/39697920#39697920).

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3 and 4** brought a lot of change also for the access levels of variables and methods. **Swift 3 and 4** now has 4 different access levels, where **open/public** access is the highest (least restrictive) access level and **private** access is the lowest (most restrictive) access level:

- **private** functions and members can only be accessed from within the scope of the entity itself (struct, class, …) and its extensions (in Swift 3 also the extensions were restricted)
- **fileprivate** functions and members can only be accessed from within the source file where they are declared.
- **internal** functions and members (which is the default, if you do not explicitly add an access level key word) can be accessed anywhere within the target where they are defined. Thats why the TestTarget doesn't have automatically access to all sources, they have to be marked as accessible in xCode's file inspector.
- **open or public** functions and members can be accessed from anywhere within the target and from any other context that imports the current target’s module.

**Interesting:**

Instead of marking every single method or member as "private", you can cover some methods (e.g. typically helper functions) in an extension of a class / struct and mark the whole extension as "Private".

```
class foo { }

private extension foo {
    func somePrivateHelperFunction01() { }
    func somePrivateHelperFunction02() { }
    func somePrivateHelperFunction03() { }
}
```

This can be a good idea, in order to get better maintainable code. And you can easily switch (e.g. for unit testing) to non-private by just changing one word.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

Comment: Well, this answer was valid in the previous Swift version(s), it seems that it is not valid anymore :) please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-has-access-modifiers/39697920#39697920).

Answer (score 1):

One of the options you could use is to wrap the instance creation into a function and supply the appropriate getters and setters in a constructor:

```
class Counter {
    let inc: () -> Int
    let dec: () -> Int

    init(start: Int) {
        var n = start

        inc = { ++n }
        dec = { --n }
    }
}


let c = Counter(start: 10)

c.inc()  // 11
c.inc()  // 12
c.dec()  // 11
```

Answer (score 0):

The [language grammar](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/zzSummaryOfTheGrammar.html) does not have the keywords 'public', 'private' or 'protected'.  This would suggest everything is public.  Of course, there could be some alternative method of specifying access modifiers without those keywords but I couldn't find it in the language reference.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully to save some time for those who want something akin to protected methods:

As per other answers, swift now provides the 'private' modifier - which is defined file-wise rather than class-wise such as those in Java or C# for instance.  This means that if you want protected methods, you can do it with swift private methods *if they are in the same file*

1. Create a base class to hold 'protected' methods (actually private)
2. Subclass this class to use the same methods
3. In other files you cannot access the base class methods, even when you subclass either

e.g. File 1:

```
class BaseClass {
    private func protectedMethod() {
        
    }
}

class SubClass : BaseClass {
    func publicMethod() {
        self.protectedMethod()  //this is ok as they are in same file
    }
}
```

File 2:

```
func test() {
    var a = BaseClass()
    a.protectedMethod() //ERROR


    var b = SubClass()
    b.protectedMethod() //ERROR
}

class SubClass2 : BaseClass {
    func publicMethod() {
        self.protectedMethod() //ERROR
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

till swift 2.0 there were only three access level [Public, internal, private]
but in swift 3.0 apple added two new access level which are [ Open, fileType ] so 
now in swift 3.0 there are 5 access level 
Here I want to clear the role of these two access level 
1. Open: this is much similar to Public but the only difference is that the Public 
   can access the subclass and override, and Open access level can not access that    [this image is taken from Medium website and this describe the difference between open and public access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nv7f.png)

Now to second new access level
2. filetype is bigger version of private or less access level than internal 
   The fileType can access the extended part of the [class, struct, enum]
   and private can not access the extended part of code it can only access the 
   lexical scope 
   [this image is taken from Medium website and this describe the difference between fileType and Private access level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iST5w.png)