# Kotlin: fun vs val

Tags: kotlin, methods, properties, computed-properties

Kotlin supports *computed properties* but I am not sure when to use them.

Let's say I have a class:

```kotlin
class Car(val color: String)
```

and have this function that returns `true` if the car is white:

```kotlin
fun isWhite(car: Car): Boolean {
  return car.color == "WHITE"
}
```

Now I want this function to be a *member function* (a *method*); this would look like this:

```kotlin
class Car(val color: String) {
  fun isWhite(): Boolean = color == "WHITE"
}
```

but it can also look like this:

```kotlin
class Car(val color: String) {
  val isWhite: Boolean get() = color == "WHITE"
}
```

So, which one is better?

Comment: See the relevant [Swift question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24035276/8583692).

Comment: Also see [this medium article](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-should-i-define-function-or-property-6786951da909).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The official [Kotlin Coding Conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#functions-vs-properties) defines in section *Functions vs Properties* the following:

> In some cases functions with no arguments might be interchangeable with read-only properties. Although the semantics are similar, there are some stylistic conventions on when to prefer one to another.
>
> Prefer a property over a function when the underlying algorithm:
>
> - does not throw
> - is cheap to calculate (or caсhed on the first run)
> - returns the same result over invocations if the object state hasn't changed

So, I would use in the above example a `val` for `isWhite`, since it does not throw, the string comparison is cheap to calculate and the `color` of the `Car` can't change, as the `Car.color` is itself defined as `val`.

##### Compiled difference

Note that the JVM bytecode of the `get()` block will get compiled to the exact same code as the function would have. So, both approaches are the same regarding the compiled bytecode and [there is no performance difference](https://itsronald.com/blog/2016/06/kotlin-get-property-vs-method).

Comment: can someone explain what does it means "does not throw" , does it means "I am sure that this property would NEVER throw any exception" ?

Comment: @elliotching yes, exactly.

Comment: Regarding "cheap to calculate" - isn't that an implementation detail?

Answer (score 3):

To add to other answers, these are from the book *[Java to Kotlin](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/java-to-kotlin/9781492082262/)*, chapter 11 *Methods to Properties*:

#### Example 1

Suppose we want to add *age* to this class:

```kotlin
data class Person(val dateOfBirth: LocalDate)
```

We can compute age easily (ignoring time zones) from the `dateOfBirth` property. But this doesn’t depend only on that property; it also depends on when we call it.
Unlikely though it is, `fred.age == fred.age` can return `false`.

Age is an *action*; its result depends on when it is called. Properties
should be *calculations*, timeless and dependent only on their inputs, in this case the `dateOfBirth` property.
Hence, `age()` should be a function, not a property:

```kotlin
data class Person(val dateOfBirth: LocalDate) {
    fun age() = Period.between(dateOfBirth, LocalDate.now()).years
}
```

#### Example 2

What if we want a cryptographic hash of all the other properties of the object?
This is a *calculation* (for immutable objects), but if it is expensive to compute, it should be a method `hash()` not a property `hash`. We might even want to hint at the cost of the method in its name:

```kotlin
data class PersonWithProperties(
    val givenName: String,
    val familyName: String,
    val dateOfBirth: LocalDate
) {
    fun computeHash(): ByteArray =
        someSlowHashOf(givenName, familyName, dateOfBirth.toString())
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Personal preference.

My view would be, if you don't need to pass it anything, then create it as a property.

But if you need to pass it more information, it will have to be a function!