# Do Swift inner classes have access to self of outer class?

Tags: swift

I'm coming from a Java background where when you declare the inner class, it's either static, and doesn't have access to the instance of the outer class, or it's not static, and can access the instance of the outer class that's being operated on. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_class#Types_of_nested_classes_in_Java

Does Swift have any concept of this? From my testing, I cannot seem to get access to the `Outer`'s `self` object, but I definitely could be doing something wrong.

```
class Outer {
    let value = ""
    class Inner {
        func foo() {
            let bar = value // 'Outer.Type' does not have a member named 'value'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't access the outer class out-of-the-box.

But what you can do is:

```
class Outer {

    let value = ""
    var inner = Inner()

    class Inner {

        weak var parent: Outer! = nil

        func foo() {
            let bar = parent.value
        }

    }

    init() {
        inner.parent = self
    }

}
```

Or:

```
class Outer {

    class Inner {

        unowned let parent: Outer

        init(parent: Outer) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

    }

    let value = ""
    var inner: Inner! = nil

    init() {
        inner = Inner(parent: self)
    }

}
```

Comment: Your solution limits you to a single instance of the Inner class per Outer. I don't think this is desired in general, but would be fine in certain circumstances. If you set the reference in Inner's constructor you'd get around this.

Comment: I've marked this as the solution, since I think this the closest we can get with Swift right now (assuming you setup the ref inside inner's init instead). However, I think an alternative way to look at this problem is that Swift doesn't support inner classes accessing the outer class's scope. Your solution is basically achieving this by doing all the work manually. This approach reminds me of attempts to create instanced methods through using static functions that take a reference to this/self as their first argument.

Comment: Wny would you not declare the outer class (in Inner) as unowned - such as: unowned var parent: Outer

Comment: @inder: it simply would not work with unowned.  Swift returns compile-error.  Do you have a snippet that illustrates what you mean?

Comment: @inder unowned and var do not go together. If you change to unowned you must also change to use let. This forces you to use a constructor for Inner (which is good, see my first comment). The code would look like: class Outer {
        let value = ""

        func baz() {
            var inner = Inner(parent: self)
        }

        class Inner {
            unowned let parent: Outer
            init(parent: Outer) {
                self.parent = parent
            }

            func foo() {
                let bar = parent.value
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @Sky thanks for clarifying - I surely got the syntax wrong. What I was trying to convey, though, is that using unowned references was probably a better option here.

Comment: Note that `unowned` is same as `weak`, except that **`unowned` ensures we get a fatal-error, if we access the variable after parent is deallocated** (it just forces you to write `let bar = parent.value` instead of `let bar = parent?.value ?? "my-default"`, and any nil check results in compile-error); But if we use `!` like `weak var parent: Outer!` in above example, then even `weak` results in a nice fatal-error (once parent is `nil`) and there is not much difference!!!

Answer (score 3):

No and to have similar feature in Swift you need to hard code it.

```
class Outer {
    var value = 0

    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func inner() -> Inner {
        return Inner(self)
    }

    class Inner {
        let outer: Outer
        var value = 1

        init(_ outer: Outer) {
            self.outer = outer
        }

        func doSomething() {
            print("Outer ", outer.value, " Inner ", value)
        }
    }
}

let i1 = Outer(1).inner()
i1.doSomething() // Outer 1 Inner 1

let i2 = Outer(2).inner()
i2.doSomething() // Outer 2 Inner 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Nested types don't have any special access to the types that contain them. But I don't think that's all that's going on here. You seem to be a little fuzzy on classes versus instances.

`value` is a property of the Outer class. That means each instance of Outer has its own `value`. Inner is a separate class that exists in the namespace of Outer. So when you write `let bar = value`, there is no such thing as `value` to access, because that only exists in instances of Outer, and we don't have any instances at hand. If it were a class property, you could do `let bar = Outer.value`.

Comment: Hmm, so if Swift is using the 'class' keyword to mean static for properties/functions, then in a way we're forced to declare our inner classes static when we use the 'class' keyword to define them.

Comment: @Sky: I don't think so, because that class is not a property or a function. It's just the normal `class` keyword that begins a class definition.

Comment: "You seem to be a little fuzzy on classes versus instances." I don't think so, because in Java, you *would* be able to access instance variable `value` of the Outer class from an instance of the inner class.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the problem like this:

```
class Outer {
    let value = ""
    class Inner {
        func foo(outer: Outer) {
            let bar = outer.value
        }
    }
}
```

Or instead of passing the `Outer` instance to the `foo` method, you could pass it to an initializer for `Inner`. But that trick wouldn't work if `Inner` were an `enum` because a Swift `enum` can't have properties (other than associated values, which are like properties).

This workaround is the equivalent of what Java does implicitly for an inner class, to avoid burdening you with the busywork of passing an argument and explicitly referencing through it.

IMO the rationale for Java's inner class feature is similar to the rationale for closures: the feature allows code to implicitly use variables from the environment (in this case the environment is the `Outer` class instance). I don't know why Swift lacks inner classes. Lots of existing Swift code will have to be changed to put `static` in front of class declarations if Swift is enhanced to do inner classes. Worth it, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use inheritance so that you use outer as superclass of inner.

```
class Outer {
    let value = ""
    class Inner: Outer {
        func foo() {
            let bar = value //value is now accessable as it has internal access from the superclass
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So why don't *you* start with it? :)

Comment: Well I copied the code from above and only realized when I finished my answer but ok I'll change it

Comment: I think this is my fault, my question doesn't explain why we want an inner class. Your solution does "solve" my stripped down code example, but it doesn't really allow us to have the mechanism we want. The inner class is supposed to be a tool for the outer class to use. See https://www.google.com/?#q=java+inner+class+use for more detailed explanations of what I was looking for.

Comment: Instance of such `Inner` class does not have access to `Outer` class instance.

Answer (score 0):

Inner classes in any language are a pretty much useless construct. They do nothing for separation of concerns. They only provide a visual grouping of internals of the wrapper class, but the code remains highly entangled with cross-dependencies all over the place.

The proper practice of abstraction is to isolate pieces which deal with as minimum a set of problems as possible (ideally, one). Isolation implies that there are no cross-dependencies possible, which makes a huge deal when it comes to reasoning about the code.

Ask yourself: what do you really need this reference to the outer class for? 
The only possible answer is to merely get access to some particular part of its API.
Turns out, that is what makes specialising the inner class to the specific outer class a redundancy.

Consider the following example:

```
class CustomSectionContentController : UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

  lazy var webViewDelegate: WebViewDelegate = WebViewDelegate()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = webViewDelegate
  }

  class WebViewDelegate: NSObject, UIWebViewDelegate {

    var overlay: ProgressOverlay?

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
      // Here I want to access the 'view' of the outer class:
      overlay = ProgressOverlay.cover(outerSelf.view)
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
      overlay?.remove()
    }

  }
}
```

While, of course, you can work around the missing `outerSelf` functionality with either of the multiple approaches suggested in the other answers, this example actually shows that there's an easily distinguishable piece of code, which could be isolated. Consider the following alternative:

```
class CustomSectionContentController : UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

  lazy var webViewDelegate: ProgressOverlayWebViewDelegate =
    ProgressOverlayWebViewDelegate(view: self.view)

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView.delegate = webViewDelegate
  }

}

class ProgressOverlayWebViewDelegate: NSObject, UIWebViewDelegate {

  let view: UIView

  init(view: UIView) {
    self.view = view
  }

  var overlay: ProgressOverlay?

  func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    overlay = ProgressOverlay.cover(view)
  }

  func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    overlay?.remove()
  }

}
```

See the difference? Our controller now doesn't deal with the problem area of a WebView delegate at all. We now also have an isolated general `ProgressOverlayWebViewDelegate`, which knows nothing about the controller which uses it. This means that we can reuse this delegate in other controllers.

You might not believe it at first, but it actually turns out that the above approach applies to **all** scenarios involving inner classes. Isolation of concerns is the cornerstone of good practices of abstraction and programming in general, so whenever you bump into this kind of a problem reconsider.

Comment: I think you're wrong at least in terms of inner classes as they exist in Swift. All inner classes do in Swift is namespace them to the enclosing type. They have no references to the enclosing type's data at all. For instance, if one were to create a linked list, one would probably make it's `Node` an inner class so that it doesn't clutter up the name space.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many inner classes and want to write less lines of code then you can create base class with initializer that accepts `Outer` instance and inherit all inner classes from it:

```
class Outer {
    func testInner() {
        print("test")
    }

    class InnerBase {
        let outer: Outer

        init(outer: Outer) {
            self.outer = outer
        }
    }

    class Inner1: InnerBase {
        func test() {
            outer.testInner()
        }
    }

    class Inner2: InnerBase {
        func test() {
            outer.testInner()
        }
    }

    func test() {
        Inner1(outer: self).test()
        Inner2(outer: self).test()
    }
}

Outer().test()
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't like any of these solutions, mainly because a nested class should not know about its parent.

You can do something like this:

```
class Outer {
    let value = ""

    class Inner {
        let innerValue: String

        init(value: String) {
            self.innerValue = value
        }

        func foo() {
            let bar = self.innerValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer does not attempt to show or explain how the inner class accesses the `value` property of the outer class. In the code you posted, none of the code in `Inner` is accessing the `value` property of `Outer`.