# swift class declared inside method can not reach method?

Tags: swift

I am using XCTest and declaring classes inside the TestMethod as a means of Mocking a class.  However, It seems that the class is unable to call a method outside of its declaration.  how do I fix this?

```
class MyTestCase : XCTestCase {
    func testExample() {
        class Bar {  // <-- the class declared inside a function
            func Barkly() {
                 foo(); // <-- apparently this produces a compile error.
            }
        }
    }

    func foo() { //<-- this is the method I am trying to call
        println("hello world")
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you already try to first create a MyTestCase object then call the foo method?

Comment: Yes I have.  It can't find a MyTestCase defined anywhere.  I'm not sure how to make it available.

Comment: Might be a scope issue with only being able to access the class's functions. Maybe take the class Bar out of the function and just have it nested within the main class instead of being nested within the main class and the function

Comment: In fact you shouldn't try to call the function directly, you could just return it and the use, functional style.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Swift inner classes have access to self of outer class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815384/do-swift-inner-classes-have-access-to-self-of-outer-class)