# How to update a variable in a class from a nested class swift

Tags: xcode, class, variables, swift

I was wondering how I can update variables in a class from within a nested class:

```
class one {
    var x:Int = 0;
    var y:Int = 0;
    var z:Int = 0;
    var questionFive:Int = 0;

    let totalq = 5;

    internal var totalright = 0;

    class two: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            x++;
            y++;
            z++;
        }
    }

}
```

With the code above it will return the error

> 'one.Type' does not have a member named 'x'

(and the same error code for y and z).

Therefore I was wondering how I can update a variable from a nested class with swift?

Comment: [You cannot do it out of the box, but there is a trick that you can use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27139165/335858).

Comment: Follow the link to find out :) The linked answer shows a small example.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it doesn't work it gives the same error on the `let questionOneanswers = questionOneanswer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     var obj = one()
     obj.x++;
     obj.y++;
     obj.z++;
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this returns the exception "expected declaration"