# Call delegate from inner class

Tags: swift

Have a class with an inner class. The inner class needs to call the delegate defined in the outer class. I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815384/do-swift-inner-classes-have-access-to-self-of-outer-class) about accessing classes from inner classes and it got me going in the correct direction. Unfortunately, I didn't find any questions about doing this with protocols. When ran the outer class in the inner class is always nil. Here is the code

```
protocol CallBackDelegate {
    func afterSetting()
}

public class CallBack {
  fileprivate static var instance: inner?
  var delegate: CallBackDelegate?
  var outer: CallBack?

  @discardableResult
  public static func show(text: String, _ callBack: Bool = false) -> Bool{
    instance = inner(text: text, callBack)
    instance?.callBack()
    return true
  }


  fileprivate class inner: UIView {
    var hasCallBack = false
    var textLabel: UILabel!

    convenience init(text: String, callBack: Bool) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 120))

        textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: 20))
        textLabel.textAlignment = .center
        textLabel.text = text

        hasCallBack = callBack
    }

    func callBack() {
        addSubview(textLabel)
        if hasCallBack { outer.delegate?.afterSetting() }
    }
  }


  init() {
    outer = self
  }
}
```

The area throwing nil is

```
if hasCallBack { outer.delegate?.afterSetting() }
```

I did try defining the parent to the inner on the instance (instance?.outer = self) but it gave me the message of "Cannot assign value of type CallBack.Type to type CallBack. I then went the init way after trying numerous other ways.

Any advice/assistance is much appreciated on getting to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might be forgetting to initialize the delegate? It is declared, but you never set up a value to the variable.