# Data encapsulation in Swift

Tags: encapsulation, swift

I've read the entire [Swift book](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11), and watched all the [WWDC videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) (all of which I heartily recommend). One thing I'm worried about is data encapsulation.

Consider the following (entirely contrived) example:

```
class Stack<T>
{
    var items : T[] = []

    func push( newItem: T ) {
        items.insert( newItem, atIndex: 0 )
    }

    func pop() -> T? {
        if items.count == 0 {
            return nil;
        }

        return items.removeAtIndex( 0 );
    }
}
```

This class implements a stack, and implements it using an Array. Problem is, `items` (like all properties in Swift) is public, so nothing is preventing anyone from directly accessing (or even mutating) it separate from the public API. As a curmudgeonly old C++ guy, this makes me very grumpy.

I see people bemoaning the lack of access modifiers, and while I agree they would directly address the issue (and I hear rumors that they might be implemented Soon (TM) ), I wonder what some strategies for data hiding would be in their absence.

Have I missed something, or is this simply an omission in the language?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24003918/1639670

Comment: There is an actual half way to do some sort of data hidding - protocols. Just make your class conform to your protocol with all functions and stuff you want to be visible to the outside world and pass it instead of the class itself. As i said this is not replacement, but will work till the visibility modifiers are out. Also this is a good design pattern - dependancy injection

Comment: " so nothing is preventing anyone from directly accessing (or even mutating) it separate from the public API" - aside from being a "curmudgeonly old C++ guy" :-) what harm do you think will happen if you don't forcibly prevent people from using your code the way they want to? Python, for instance, has a saying "We're all adults here." Public/private is based on documentation and convention. If someone wants to fiddle with something internal to the class, caveat emptor. No one pretends they can know for all eternity that no one will ever have a good reason to access an internal object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simply missing at the moment. Greg Parker has explicitly stated ([in this dev forums thread](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/227288)) that visibility modifiers are coming.

Given that there aren't headers, the standard Objective-C tricks won't work, and I can't think of another trick to limit visibility that doesn't involve lots of bending over backwards. Since the language feature has been promised I'm not sure it's worth any big investment.

On the bright side since this feature *is* in flux, now is a great time to [file a radar](https://bugreport.apple.com) and influence how it turns out.

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer for future reference.

From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html):

> **Access Levels**
>
> Swift provides three different access levels for
> entities within your code. These access levels are relative to the
> source file in which an entity is defined, and also relative to the
> module that source file belongs to.
>
> **Public access** enables entities to
> be used within any source file from their defining module, and also in
> a source file from another module that imports the defining module.
> You typically use public access when specifying the public interface
> to a framework.
>
> **Internal access** enables entities to be used within any
> source file from their defining module, but not in any source file
> outside of that module. You typically use internal access when
> defining an app’s or a framework’s internal structure.
>
> **Private access**
> restricts the use of an entity to its own defining source file. Use
> private access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece
> of functionality. Public access is the highest (least restrictive)
> access level and private access is the lowest (or most restrictive)
> access level.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact I was delighted Swift finally adopted static typing so conforming to the theory for code with optimal OO properties, still the fall of the headers breaks the very meniang of Object Orienting programming, namely encapsulation. A way out would be like for Eiffel to automaticaly extract the headers but without specifying which are the public interfaces and which the private ones, it would be wortheless. I am really lambasted at this move of Apple's.