# How do I restrict a property to a range?

Tags: properties, swift

There are a cases where I might want to model data where it makes sense for a value to be restricted to a given range.

For example, if I want to represent a "mammal", I might want to restrict a `legs` property to 0–4.

My first attempt is shown below:

```
class Mammal {
    var _numLegs:Int?

    var numLegs:Int {
    get {
        return _numLegs!
    }
    set {
        if 0...4 ~= newValue {
            self._numLegs = newValue
        }
        else {
            self._numLegs = nil
        }
    }
    }
}
```

However, this seems unsatisfactory since all properties are "public" there is nothing stopping the customer of the class from setting `Mammal._numLegs` to some arbitrary value.

Any better ways to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure in swift, but in objective-C, doing Mammal.numLegs = 5 called the setter (if you have a property with a custom setter).

Comment: rather than underscore you should use something much harder to type like: 

Comment: In all seriousness, you can use a `didSet` property observer and check if its out of bounds there

Comment: As [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-have-access-modifiers) states, there *will be* access modifiers in Swift eventually. It's just a beta now. So I think that ignoring the fact that someone can access fields that should be private is OK for now.

Comment: I agree with @FreeNickname, waiting until access modifiers are available is probably the best solution. Maybe just add a `FIXME` or similar that reminds you to revisit it in your code later.

Comment: @JackWu `didSet` looks spot on as it avoids the need for an intermediate property. Do you want to make the comment into an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Another option is to use a protocol, like so: http://devblog.reverb.com/post/88673812266/private-methods-and-properties-in-swift

Comment: "However, this seems unsatisfactory since all properties are public there is nothing stopping the customer of the class from setting Mammal._numLegs to some arbitrary value." It's not your job to stop people from using your code. Perhaps 20 years down the line someone will need to fiddle with Mammal._numlegs. You just document the official public API and anyone who does anything else does it at their own risk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for fun I decided to write a snippet with @jackWu's suggestion (+1) in order to try that `didSet` thing:

```
class Mammal {
    var numLegs:UInt? {
        didSet { if numLegs? > 4 { numLegs = nil } }
    }

    init() {
        numLegs = nil
    }
}
```

It works perfectly. As soon as you try to set numLegs to 5 or greater, boom, it gets nilled automatically. Please note that I used Uint to avoid negative leg quantities :)

I really like the elegance of `didSet`.

Comment: @jackWu you posted while I was writing. Let me know if you want me to delete my answer.

Comment: @JackWu I've accepted @JeanLeMoignan's answer because the use of `UInt` and the optional seems a bit more elegant and readable. Thanks for pointing out `didSet`

Comment: No problem, I do like this answer. I didn't use the optional because your original code had it as non-optional. Karma is not as important as a good answer :]

Comment: Since you guys seem to like `didSet` so much, I'd just like to throw in here that `willSet` is available too! Also, inside `didSet` you can access the previous value with `oldValue`. And you can define `willSet(newValue) { }` and access `newValue` in there as well! Refer to :https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Properties.html

Comment: Hmmm, good point @jackWu. Could be useful in cases we must react _before_ any value gets written.

Comment: What exactly do you have against those with a negative number of legs? Are you a negative gigot bigot?

Comment: It's worth noting that 'The Swift Programming Language' [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID320) discourages the use of `UInt` just to restrict the range of an integer, citing code interoperability and avoided type conversions as the reason

Answer (score 5):

In this specific case, you want a `property observer`, you could implement it like this:

```
class Mammal {
    init () {
        numLegs = 0
        super.init()
    }
    var numLegs:Int {
        didSet: {
            if !(numLegs ~= 0...4) {
               numLegs = max(0,min(numLegs,4)) // Not sure if this is what you want though
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at this though, I'm not sure if this would recurse and call `didSet` again...I guess it wouldn't be too bad because it would pass the check the second time