# Swift: where to place IBAction functions for clean class code

Tags: swift, coding-style, ibaction

What is your best practice with IBActions? Where do u place them? I cannnot decide.

1) If I place them with regular functions, it can be messy but everything if private.

2) When I place them as `extension ClassName{}` It is more clean BUT it can't work with `private` variables I have to make them unprivate.

I want to code clean. Thx

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, your case is when you add them to an `extension`, you won't be able to access `private` vars/methods.

You have (what I suggest) two possible solutions:

**1-** If you want to keep them in a separated extension (but in the same *.swift* file) for the purpose of organizing your code, you need to change `private` to `fileprivate`.

For more information about access modifiers in Swift 3, you might want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-have-access-modifiers/39697920#39697920).

**2-** Keep them in the ViewController and use `// MARK: - IBActions`, it marks sections in the symbol navigator.

For example:

[image]

As you can see, there are `// MARK: - Core Data stack`, `// MARK: - Core Data Saving support` and `//MARK: - Machines Core Data` to separate the code and make it more readable and organized.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Well, for me, I prefer to keep them in scope of the ViewController class. But that's doesn't means that is is "better", especially when talking about performance of the app, that shouldn't add any effects at all...