# In Swift, what is the difference between the Access modifiers internal and public?

Tags: swift, swift3

Swift offers 5 access modifiers: `open`, `public`, `internal`, `fileprivate` and `private`.

Of what I know about these specifiers, (mainly from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-have-access-modifiers) & [link_2](https://medium.com/@ryuichi/swift-3-access-control-e8035ce8569e#.s00co3sp5))

**`open`** means classes and class members can be subclassed and overridden both within and outside the defining module (target).

**`fileprivate`** restricts the use of an entity to its defining source file. Basically accessible by multiple classes within a single file.

**`private`** restricts the use of an entity to its enclosing declaration.

Now, public and internal seems pretty much the same to me :-

**`public`** means classes and class members can only be subclassed and overridden *within the defining module* (target).

**`internal`** enables an entity to be *used within the defining module* (target). Also, this happens to be the default specifier if nothing else is mentioned. We would typically use internal access when defining an app’s or a framework’s internal structure.

So basically how do public and internal differ?

This is my first Question here, so if I have missed out any details, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `public` are visible outside of defining module, `internal` aren't

Comment: @user28434 I believe `public` is visible only within the defining module.

Comment: @user28434, you may refer to the links mentioned for confirmation.

Comment: you believe wrong, and you may refer to Apple doc directly and/or try it in code yourself

Comment: @iCode your second link also says: *allows other modules to use the public classes and the public members*

Comment: @Keiwan, my answer has just one link

Comment: @user28434 My bad, I meant to tag the OP.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-have-access-modifiers/39697920#39697920

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever you marked as **public** can be use within your app and outside of you app(module). If you marked something as **internal** that can only be used within your app(module). This is very helpful when your developing a library (framework) , you can use internal to hide library structure.
And Public members of A.swift and B.swift are available to C.swift and D.swift. The only restriction is that classes can't be subclassed (they would need to be **open**.)
- My answer base on @Keaz & @Alexander.

Answer (score 1):

From [Access Control manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html):

> **Open** access and **public** access enable entities to be used within any
> source file from their defining module, **and also in a source file from
> another module that imports the defining module**. You typically use
> open or public access when specifying the public interface to a
> framework. The difference between open and public access is described
> below.
>
> **Internal** access enables entities to be used within any source
> file from their defining module, but **not in any source file outside of
> that module**. You typically use internal access when defining an app’s
> or a framework’s internal structure.

Difference is in visibility to other modules.

EDIT to answer @iCode comment:

You don't need all of them.

For simplest small single-dev application just using default `internal` will be enough.

If you will need to do it right you may add `fileprivate`/`private` accessors to hide some implementation.

If you're developing large app and want to separate code into modules, or if you're developing library you will need to use `public`/`open` to create inter-module interface.

Comment: Just got these details from @user28434's provided link. `public` is **accessible** (note only **accessible**, there is no option for **subclassing/overriding**) outside the defining module. `open` however offers both accessiblity and overridability even outside its module. Finally `internal` is not even accessible outside its own module. However I wonder if we actually would use so many different types in a single project!