# Is there a way to encapsulate certain properties in a Swift protocol so they aren't visible to users of the protocol?

Tags: swift, protocols, implementation, protected

I am looking for a way to encapsulate certain properties in a Swift protocol to hide them from users of the protocol while making them available to types implementing the protocol.

Here is a simple illustrative example.

Say we are implementing the `Command` pattern, as shown below:

```
protocol Command {
    func execute()
}

class OneCommand: Command {
    private let target: CommandTarget
    
    init(target: CommandTarget) {
        self.target = target
    }
    
    func execute() {
        target.number = 1
    }
}

class TwoCommand: Command {
    private let target: CommandTarget
    
    init(target: CommandTarget) {
        self.target = target
    }
    
    func execute() {
        target.number = 2
    }
}
```

To enable these commands to undo themselves, the standard method is to have each command save the state of the target object before performing its action in the `execute()` method. The `undo()` method can then restore the state of the target object using this saved state.

Since the undo action is the same for all commands, one would want to implement it only once in an extension to the protocol. To be able to do that, however, both the variable in which the state is saved and the variable which stores a reference to the target object cannot be `private` since a protocol cannot have `private` properties.

The protocol will change as shown below:

```
protocol Command {
    var target: CommandTarget { get }
    var savedState: Int? { get set }
    func execute()
    func undo()
}
```

Each concrete command will have to be rewritten as follows:

```
class OneCommand: Command {
    let target: CommandTarget
    var savedState: Int?
    
    init(target: CommandTarget) {
        self.target = target
    }
    
    func execute() {
        savedState = target.number
        target.number = 1
    }
}
```

The `undo()` method can then be added through an extension to the protocol.

```
extension Command {
    func undo() {
        guard let savedState else { return }
        target.number = savedState
    }
}
```

This, however, also exposes the `target` and `savedState` properties to users of the protocol, exposing parts of the implementation of the protocol, which is not the intention.

Is there a way in Swift which would make the `target` and `savedState` properties available to types implementing the protocol, and in extensions to the protocol, without exposing them to users of the protocol.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to declare a 'protected' variable in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41764977/how-to-declare-a-protected-variable-in-swift)

Comment: Java's `protected` won't help here either. Interface methods in Java can't be `protected`. Looking at protocols that have "hidden implementation details" in Apple's libraries, you'd use a macro to synthesise the protocol conformance and the implementation of `undo`.

Comment: The default implementation of `undo` assumes the `target` has type `CommandTarget`, as well as the fact that `savedState` is a saved state of the `number` property (as opposed to any other property in `CommandTarget`). Is that true for all commands?

Comment: Thanks @lazarevzubov. I had seen this question before asking mine. It doesn't really provide what I was looking for, which is to encapsulate certain protocol properties so they are only available to types conforming to the protocol, and in extensions to the protocol. The only way it seems is to create the protocol and the conforming types and extension in a separate module and then use the internal keyword for the properties to be encapsulated. Not ideal, imo.

Comment: Hi @Sweeper. The `undo()` method has to restore the state saved by the `execute()` method of each concrete command. Hence, it assumes that the `savedState` property contains the state to be restored to undo the effect of the command. This is a simplified example to illustrate the point, not an ideal implementation of the `Command` pattern in Swift.

Comment: Okay. I'd suggest to just give up on this then. If you have more boilerplate than `undo`, consider writing a macro to generate the boilerplate implementation, like how `@Observable` generates lots of boilerplate implementation details for `Observable`