# Public Vs Internal Access Modifier

Tags: ios, swift, access-modifiers

I have gone through the Apple provided document i.e https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html

Here, it explains:

> Classes with **public access**, or any more restrictive access level,
>   can be subclassed only within the module where they’re defined.
>
> **Internal access** enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, but not in any source file outside of that
>   module. You typically use internal access when defining an app’s or a
>   framework’s internal structure.
>
> **Open classes** can be subclassed within the module where they’re defined, and within any module that imports the module where they’re
>   defined

I am not finding the exact difference between the **public** and **Internal** access.

My research includes http://www.globalnerdy.com/2014/07/23/a-first-look-at-swifts-new-access-levels/ as well. But as per swift3.3 documentation, its not clear.

Comment: Internal classes are not accessible at all outside of the defining module. Public classes are accessible outside of the defining module, but cannot be subclassed

Comment: As said in the documentation you link to "*Open access and public access enable entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, and also in a source file from another module that imports the defining module*" :)

Comment: Did you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-have-access-modifiers ?

Comment: Thanks Martin for this "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-have-access-modifiers" link. Its helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Swift have access modifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003918/does-swift-have-access-modifiers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift’s access control model is based on the concept of `modules` and `source files.`

A module is a single unit of code distribution—a framework or application that is built and shipped as a single unit and that can be imported by another module with Swift’s `import` keyword.

For example, some popular modules: Alamofire, SwiftyJson, RxSwift ...
These modules you are importing into your project. All classes that are using `internal access level` can be used only inside these libs/ modules. You cannot use them directly in your code.
But if the class is `public` - you can use it in your sources directly.