# Referring to a type in another module with the same name as a type in the current module when the other module has a type with its own name in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftpm

I am using the swift package manager.
I have a module `ModuleA` which exports two types: `ModuleA` and `Test`.
I have a module `ModuleB` which defines a single type: `Test`.
In `ModuleB`, how can I refer to the type `Test` from `ModuleA`?
Ideally, I would like syntax such as `#module(ModuleA)` to refer directly to the module `ModuleA`.

Reproducible example:

`Package.swift`:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "ShadowingTest",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "ModuleA",
            targets: ["ModuleA"]),
        .library(
            name: "ModuleB",
            targets: ["ModuleB"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "ModuleA",
            dependencies: []),
        .target(
            name: "ModuleB",
            dependencies: ["ModuleA"]),
    ]
)
```

`Sources/ModuleA/ModuleA.swift`:

```swift
public enum ModuleA {}
public struct Test {
    public static let module: String = "ModuleA"
}
```

`Sources/ModuleB/ModuleB.swift`:

```swift
import ModuleA

struct Test {
    static let module: String = "ModuleB"
}

func test() {
    print(ModuleA.Test.module)
}
```

Running `swift build` errors with

```
Sources/ModuleB/ModuleB.swift:8:19: error: type 'ModuleA' has no member 'Test'
```

but succeeds when `public` is removed from the `ModuleA` enum in `ModuleA`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the issue is `ModuleA` enum in ModuleA module does not have `Test`.

When you remove `public` in `ModuleA enum` then `ModuleB` cannot recognize there is a `ModuleA enum` because its access modifier is `internal` by default so `ModuleB` recognizes `Test` struct in `ModuleA` instead of trying to find `Test` in `ModuleA enum`

---

Bonus: There is a [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24012515/7512091) in SO about access modifiers I think you'll find useful.

---

EDIT:

If you need to use `ModuleA.Test` even there is an enum named `ModuleA` then you can use `import (class|struct|func|protocol|enum) <needed_component>` so in your case you should import like this:

```swift
import struct ModuleA.Test
```

If you want to use the struct with another name to avoid naming conflicts then you can set a typealias ->

```swift
import struct ModuleA.Test

typealias TestA = ModuleA.Test
```

Comment: I understand what the access modifiers are doing, but this does not answer my question. My issue is that I cannot access the `Test` type from the module `ModuleA` if the module `ModuleA` exports a `ModuleA` type. If there is no such type, `ModuleA.Test` refers to the `Test` type from the module `ModuleA`, but if there is such a type, `ModuleA.Test` refers to the static member `Test` from the enum `ModuleA` from the module `ModuleA` (which does not exist). I want to access `Test` from module `ModuleA` when module `ModuleA` exports type `ModuleA`.

Comment: @deaton.dg I've updated my answer could you please check?

Comment: This works, thank you! Ideally, I would prefer syntax like `#module(ModuleA)` to refer specifically to the module (question edited accordingly). I will accept this answer in a couple days if this is still the solution I am using.